# How to solve `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError) on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I run migration on heroku it gives me an error

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on testing-app... up, run.9199
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /app/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rake:3:in `load'
from /app/bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you setup database first on heroku?

Comment: When I run heroku run rake db:create. It also show same error

Comment: `heroku run rake db:setup` try this or check any gem which issue this exception